# Regex that selects the first numbers to appear, in a loop

Tags: regex, vba

so basically i have these types  of  strings

[image: Unique]

[image: Decimal string]

[image: Hundred]

and i would like to replaces the firsts numbers to appear, unfortunately they sometimes come in hundreds decimals or uniques. Here is the code and the patterns that i tried using.

```
Sub Validator()
Dim r As Range
Dim s As String
Dim news As String
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim regex2 As New RegExp
regex.Global = True
regex.Pattern = ",[\s\S]*$"
regex2.Pattern = "(^|\\s)([0-9]+)($|\\s)"


Sheet1.Activate


For Each r In Range("B1:B17")
    s = r.Value
    
    news = regex2.Replace(s, " ")
    
    r.Value = news

Next r

End Sub
```

Please ignore pattern 1 he basically takes out everythign after the comma and it is succesful the problem is pattern 2 which is doing basically nothing when i execute my code and i know the code is functional because the first one came out correctly.

A3 Sport 1.8 16V TFSI S-tronic 3p

A3 Sedan Prestige Plus 1.4 TFSI Flex Tip

TT 1.8 TB 180cv

Should be the end results

Comment: Do you have more (diverse) sample data with desired results?

Comment: Perhaps try it with a capture group `^([^\d\r\n]*)\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?` https://regex101.com/r/kPn74f/1

Comment: Do you want to remove the first number? Then use `regex.Global = False` and `regex2.Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)?"`

Comment: @JvdV I have disposed the desired result according to the example string

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1, that's just a single sample. In the first line of your question you mentioned: *"unfortunately they sometimes come in hundreds decimals or uniques"*. Can you follow up on that? Please include more sample data and desired results. Not just a single sample.

Comment: Thank you @Wikto Stribizew your regex actually worked appreciate ur help

Comment: @JvdV i made more samples available but no worries wictor answer fitted

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1, right. Any reason you are using regular expressions btw? The samples you gave are perfectly done through regular VBA functions.

Comment: Really? Which funtion would be applyable i basically used regex bcs it was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: For example: `Debug.Print Mid(Split(str, ",")(0), InStr(1, str, " ") + 1, Len(str))` where str holds your string variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove the first number using

```vb
Sub Validator()
Dim r As Range
Dim s As String
Dim news As String
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim regex2 As New RegExp
regex.Global = False             ' <---- Enabling first match search only (you may also just remove this line)
regex2.Pattern = "\d+(?:\.\d+)?" ' <---- One or more digits, and an optional occurrence of
                                 '       a dot and one or more digits right after
Sheet1.Activate
For Each r In Range("B1:B17")
    s = r.Value
    r.Value = regex2.Replace(s, " ")
Next r

End Sub
```

Note the `regex.Global` default value is `False`, so you may simly remove the line with `regex.Global = False`.

If your numbers can have mixed decimal separator, like `.` and `,`, use `regex2.Pattern = "\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?"`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your examples I think I'd go with regular VBA functionality as these sample do not look too complicated.

For example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "44 A3 Sedan Prestige 1.4 TFSI Flex Tip., 8561"
Debug.Print Mid(Split(str, ",")(0), InStr(1, str, " ") + 1, Len(str))

End sub
```

If you insist on regular expressions it looks like you may just use:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "44 A3 Sedan Prestige 1.4 TFSI Flex Tip., 8561"

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^\S+\s([^,]+)"
    Debug.Print .Execute(str)(0).Submatches(0)
End With

End Sub
```

Both options return:

```
A3 Sedan Prestige 1.4 TFSI Flex Tip.
```